# Command to move directories not starting with a `.`

Tags: bash, filenames, mv

I would like to move all subdirectories in a directory not starting with `.` in bash.

For example, given this directory structure:

```
subdir1/
subdir2/
.idea/
.venv/
```

The command should only move `subdir1/` and `subdir2/` to some target destination.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use:

```bash
mv */ ../target_dir/
```

If you haven't explicitly set any bash options to change the default behavior, the pattern `*/` doesn't match folders starting with a `.` in bash (unless the `dotglob` shell option has been set). For more information see `GLOBIGNORE` using the man files: `man bash`.

Answer (score 0):

With `find`:

```
find . ! -name '.*' -type d -exec mv -- {} ../target_dir \;
```

if you only want current directory:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 ! -name '.*' -type d -exec mv -- {} ../target_dir \;
```

You can't expect reliably how `dotglob` is set.